# Where in the V8 source does the automatic cast for BinaryOperation occour?

Tags: v8

I stumbled again in the good old `'12' + 2 = '122'`

I wanted to deeply understand what happens here, so my first **thesis** was that

> Maybe Javascript casts the right operand to the type of the first one and
>   then operates, like so: `'12' + String(2) = '122'` all good...

But no, because `12 + '2' = '122'` too; So the engine's magic is clearly favoring to concat over casting to number.

My second **thesis** was then

> Maybe the engine enumerates all operands and looks for an "operator override", similar to C#? And then favor executing that over doing the self-magic thing?

My confusion got even weirder when I realized that also `'5' * '8' = 40`, it casts both operands to Number and does the operation.
The only way I could possibly really understand that was to read the V8 code directly from GitHub

The farther I could track down was at `v8/src/parsing/parser-base.h` line 2865

```
// We have a "normal" binary operation.
x = factory()->NewBinaryOperation(op, x, y, pos);
if (op == Token::OR || op == Token::AND) {
  impl()->RecordBinaryOperationSourceRange(x, right_range);
}
```

From here I got lost, because I couldn't find where this `factory()` is coming from.

Long story short, where does the JavaScript "type Magic" come from in the V8 Engine Source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V8 developer here.

There are several fast paths for various cases of addition and other operations in V8. If you want to study a canonical (slow, but complete) version, you can look for [Object::Add in src/objects.cc.](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/v8/src/objects.cc?q=Object::Add&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=753)

That said, the source of truth here is not any given engine's implementation, but the JavaScript specification. What the `+` operator is supposed to do is defined here: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-addition-operator-plus.
Any engine's implementation either does precisely that, or something that from the outside is indistinguishable from that -- otherwise it's a bug. It's not a coincidence that the implementation of `Object::Add` reads almost exactly like the spec ;-)

Comment: Awesome, this is precisely what I was looking for, tyvm.